# EditText weird crash on LG Optimus w/Swype (works on emulator and Droids)

Tags: android, crash, android-edittext

I have an app which works in the emulator and on Droid phones.  While testing on an LG Optimus (which BTW has Swype installed) it crashes with the following stack trace (NOTE: it is in the constructor of EditText).

What is weird is that supposed offending line in TextView (981) is the method signature for `getDefualtView(`) and there are no references to GestureDetector in EditText or TextView in 2.2 source code.

I'm presuming (or hazarding a guess that it is most likely due to Swype) and am not sure of:

1. if it is swype, then how do i
   write my code so that it is swype
   friendly?
2. if it is not swype,
   then what could it be?  Whats
   baffling is that it is in the
   constructor using default styles,
   and null for attributes.

any help is appreciated.

Kindest regards,
S-

-- stacktrace snip --

```
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.<init>(GestureDetector.java:250)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at android.view.GestureDetector.<init>(GestureDetector.java:370)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at android.view.GestureDetector.<init>(GestureDetector.java:347)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at android.view.GestureDetector.<init>(GestureDetector.java:331)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:981)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:55)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:51)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:47)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at com.mobiapps.android.gui.EditTextImpl.<init>(EditTextImpl.java:28)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at com.mobiapps.android.gui.TextFieldImpl.makeTextView(TextFieldImpl.java:23)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at com.mobiapps.android.gui.ToolkitImpl.createTextField(ToolkitImpl.java:429)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at com.mobiapps.android.gui.ToolkitImpl.createWidgets(ToolkitImpl.java:492)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at com.mobiapps.android.gui.ToolkitImpl.initializeContainer(ToolkitImpl.java:555)
05-26 12:28:23.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11912):     at com.mobiapps.common.gui.WidgetContainer.initializeImpl(WidgetContainer.java:88)
```

-- end stack trace --

Blockquote

Comment: Can you post code? You say that the crash comes from the declaration of EditText, can we see that and the actual offending lines?

Comment: Disabled Swype and still getting error.  Checking into why am getting Looper error now...

Comment: @Nicholas - here is code snippet:
`public class EditTextImpl extends EditText implements   FieldAssignListener, FieldImpl {
 private WidgetContainer container;
 private Value widget;
 private AttributeImpl attributes;
 private Value objectForNewValue;
 private Member memberForNewValue;
 private int assignedWidth;
 private String value;

 public EditTextImpl(Activity context, WidgetContainer container, Value widget, AttributeImpl attributes) {
  super(context);
  this.container = container;
  this.widget = widget;
  this.attributes = attributes;`
Oh! This gets invoked on an AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into sources and it seems that invoking `Looper.prepare()` in the UI thread will fix this exeption. But it's very strange. Are you using multiple threads?

Comment: Yes it was in a different thread; And adding a Looper.prepare() does fix it.
Wondering why it works on EMulator and Droid w/o prepare().