# Android: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown> in SAMSUNG Galaxy S

Tags: android, exception, inflate

I am having a strange error that seems to occur only in Samsung Galaxy S with Android 2.2 (I've tested the application in Motorola Milestone 2 Android 2.2 / Xperia X10 Android 1.6 / Nexus One Android 2.2 / Google G1 Android 1.5 and 1.5 emulator and in such devices the error does not occur).

The complete stack trace is:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at my.package.MyClass.b(Unknown Source)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at my.package.MyClass.a(Unknown Source)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at my.package.MyClass.updateUI(Unknown Source)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at my.package.MyClass.UpdateUITask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     ... 4 more
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:101)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     ... 16 more
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.<init>(GestureDetector.java:250)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.view.GestureDetector.<init>(GestureDetector.java:370)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.view.GestureDetector.<init>(GestureDetector.java:347)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.view.GestureDetector.<init>(GestureDetector.java:331)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:113)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28111):     ... 20 more
```

First of all, what is going on?  What is the main error? `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` or `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>` ?

This seems to occur when I am inflating a `View` whose XML (R.layout.field_editable_label_value_numeric) line 13 is:

```
        <EditText android:id="@+id/editableLabel"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

EDIT: I forgot to tell that I am using Proguard, don't know if that somehow has influence on this issue (I don't think so).

I also added the code where I think the problem is happening:

MyClass.a:

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final ArrayList<View> views = MyClass.b(inflater);

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ItemLinearLayout);

            //clear UI
            mainLayout.removeAllViews();

            //re-set all views
            for (View view : views) {
                mainLayout.addView(view);
            }
        }
}
```

MyClass.b:

```
final ArrayList<View> viewsToAdd = new ArrayList<View>();

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field_editable_label_value_numeric, null, true);
viewsToAdd.add(view);

return views;
```

Comment: Post the code where you are inflating the view

Comment: @ dymmeh I just editted and added code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but the best explanation I got was here: [Inflate a view in a background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691311/inflate-a-view-in-a-background-thread/6692007#6692007)

Basically, it seems that Samsung Galaxy S has an `EditText` implementation whose inflation can only be done in the UI Thread.

Hope this helps someone who runs into the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Don't update your UI from a background thread -- use the UI thread only.

The stack trace looks like the inflation is happening in the `doInBackground` method of an AsyncTask.  That's probably this line:

```
final ArrayList<View> views = MyClass.b(inflater);
```

If that's the case, then you should move it out of the background thread.  If the code you posted is indeed the `doInBackground`, you may also want to consider moving your `runOnUiThread` block into `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably similar problem like there: [EditText weird crash on LG Optimus w/Swype (works on emulator and Droids)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144823/edittext-weird-crash-on-lg-optimus-w-swype-works-on-emulator-and-droids)

It seems that invoking Looper.prepare() in the UI thread will fix this exeption.

More info there: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html