# Inflate a view in a background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, inflate

I have a very simple question:

Is or is it not possible to **inflate** a view (not add it to layout) in a background thread (ex: in the `doInBackground` of an `AsyncTask`)?

I know that it is possible, because I have implemented most Activities in my application this way and never had a problem, until I had this problem on a Galaxy S:  [Android: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown> in SAMSUNG Galaxy S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682730/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-13-error-inflating/)

I've been told that I *should* not inflate `Views` in background threads, but what are the specific reasons and why does my aproach work in most devices but not in Galaxy S?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `LayoutInflater` does not make any assumptions about what thread it runs on. And nothing is mentioned about this in its documentation. Also its code seams to be thread-agnostic.

On the other hand, Views that are created by `LayoutInflater` might instantiate `Handler`s in their constructors. Well, they probably shouldn't do that, but there is no requirement for them to not create/use `Handler`s in their constructors.

My guess is that Samsung Galaxy S had some modifications in its `EditText` that somehow triggers creation of `Handler` (according to crash log from your other question instance of `GestureDetector` was instantiated which in turn created new `Handler`). While default implementation doesn't do this.

---

Overall, I'd say that because there is no explicit requirement for `View`s to not use `Handler`s and `Looper`s in their constructors you can't assume inflating Views from non-UI thread is safe.

You can actually create [`HandlerThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) and try inflating `View`s inside it. But I'd say this is very risky, as in Samsung Galaxy S example the view assumes that this thread will be alive during `View` lifetime and will process all messages using its `Looper`. Which might result in crash later on.

Comment: I've reproduced this same problem on a Galaxy Nexus running the lastest stock firmware (as of this post).  Inflating views in the background is definitely no longer an option.

Comment: HandlerThread forward Message to MainLooper should can solve this problem

Answer (score 17):

With latest support lib you can use [`android.support.v4.view.AsyncLayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AsyncLayoutInflater.html) to inflate views asynchronously. Be careful though that it can fallback to inflating on UI thread if specific requirements are not met:

> For a layout to be inflated asynchronously it needs to have a parent whose generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet) is thread-safe and all the Views being constructed as part of inflation must not create any Handlers or otherwise call myLooper(). If the layout that is trying to be inflated cannot be constructed asynchronously for whatever reason, AsyncLayoutInflater will automatically fall back to inflating on the UI thread.

Answer (score 5):

> Is or is it not possible to inflate a view (not add it to layout) in a background thread (ex: in the doInBackground of an AsyncTask)?

Possible, yes. Recommended? No. As mentioned in the documentation:

> Thus, there are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:
>
> 1. Do not block the UI thread
> 2. Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

via: [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads)

**Update [02/06/19]:**

Apparently, the support library has a tool to do this:
[AsyncLayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AsyncLayoutInflater) ([Jetpack version](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/asynclayoutinflater/view/AsyncLayoutInflater)). It was introduced in version 24, around 2016 (2 years after my answer)

But, as mentioned on other answers, be careful with this tool as it can very easily backfire.